# How to send email with different subject lines for passed testcase and failed testcase using nodemailer

Tags: email, protractor, nodemailer, subject

I need to send email with nodemailer after execution completion. At completion of all the test cases,even one spec gets failed, email subject line should state that test case has been failed. and if all the test cases gets passed then it should state that all test cases has been passed successfully.

```
this.specDone = function(result) {
      if (result.failedExpectations.length > 0) {
        let mailOptions = {
          from: '"Mathur, Shruti" <xxx@xx.com>',
          to: 'xxx@xx.com',
          subject: 'Liability Management automation Report-Test Suite Failure',
          text: 'Test case completed',
          html: 'Hi Team,<br><br> Test Automation for <b>Liability Management UI</b> through Protractor has been completed. There is <b>failure</b> for one or more than one test suites.<br>Please find the attached report for reference.',
          attachments: [{
           path: 'C:/Shruti/Protractor_Autodistribution/my-app/Test/report.zip'
            }]
        };
     }else{
      let mailOptions = {
        from: '"Mathur, Shruti" <xxx@xx.com>',
        to: 'xxx@xx.com',
        subject: 'Liability Management automation Report-All Test Suite Passed',
        text: 'Test case completed',
        html: 'Hi Team,<br><br> Test Automation for <b>Liability Management UI</b> through Protractor has been completed.All Test suites are <b>passed</b> successfully.<br>Please find the attached report for reference.',
        attachments: [{
         path: 'C:/Shruti/Protractor_Autodistribution/my-app/Test/report.zip'
          }]
      };
     }
   };
```

This is my config file code, and when i execute it, nothing happens. No email gets triggered. when i dont use if condition. email gets triggered successfully.Please provide me any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement will never be triggerd.
With your informations i would say that you have to set a variable, in the afterEach Method, that says if one of your tests failed.
Then you have to use it in the afterAll Method for your if statment.

I use cucumber with protractor and handled it like this example:

```
var failed = false;

After(function (scenario) 
{
    console.log("After " + scenario.pickle.name + " in " + scenario.sourceLocation.uri + ", result: " + scenario.result.status);
    if (scenario.result.status === Status.FAILED)
    {       
        //do stuff if one test failes
        failed = true;              
        const attach = this.attach;

        return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png)
        {
            return attach(new Buffer(png, "base64"), "image/png");
        });
    }
});

AfterAll(function(callback)
{
    console.log("AfterAll");
    if (failed)
    {       
        var mailOptions = {
            from: 'yourmail', // sender address (who sends)
            //to: process.env.reportlist,
            to: 'other mail',
            subject: (process.env.COMPUTERNAME || 'testrunner') + ': WARNING! your automated test result has found error(s)', // Subject line
            text: 'Your automated test has accured an error! Visit the report for more details: 

            /*attachments: [
            {
                filename: 'report.html',
                path: htmlReport,

            }]*/
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info)
        {
            if(error)
            {
                return console.log(error);
            } 
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            console.log(info);
        });

    } else {
        fs.writeFile(errorLog + "reportLog.txt", "SUCCESS");
        let mailOptions = {
          from: '"Mathur, Shruti" <xxx@xx.com>',
          to: 'xxx@xx.com',
          subject: 'Liability Management automation Report-All Test Suite Passed',
          text: 'Test case completed',
          html: 'Hi Team,<br><br> Test Automation for <b>Liability Management UI</b> through Protractor has been completed.All Test suites are <b>passed</b> successfully.<br>Please find the attached report for reference.',
          attachments: [{
          path: 'C:/Shruti/Protractor_Autodistribution/my-app/Test/report.zip'
      }]
  };
 }
```